# How to insert values into a php array using for loop and condition

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I wanted to insert values into a php array using conditions like the way below but it is not happening.

Please let me know if there are any other ways to do that since I am getting "undefined offset" error.

```
$noarray = array();

for ($i=1; $i<=10 ;$i++)
{
    $noarray[]=$i;
    echo $noarray[$i] . "<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: What condition? Also note that if you use `$noarray[] = $i;` your array will be 0-based indexed and you try to start with the index 1.

Comment: Improve formatting and wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `$i` as a value in the `$noarray` array.

So is you take step by step, when `$i == 1` (first step in `for`) you will add in the first element of array value of the `$i` (1).
Because in php index starts from 0 you will have an array like this:
`[0 => 1]` with only one element.
At this step you try to access the array by index `$i = 1`, but you have only at index 0 value.

I don't know exactly what you try to do, but you mess with index and value.

Probably you want something like this:

```
$noarray=array();
for ($i=1; $i<=10 ;$i++)
    {
        $noarray[$i] = $i;
        echo $noarray[$i];
        echo"<br/>";       
    }
```

This way you specify at index `$i` to add value `$i`. You can change this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ***access*** the array key with advance relative to the moment it was actually set.
The correct access to the current key should be as follows:

```
...
$noarray[] = $i;
echo $noarray[$i - 1];
```

OR like it was mentioned in the previous answer:

```
...
$noarray[$i] = $i;
echo $noarray[$i];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
    $noarray[] = $i;
    $noarray[0] = 0;
    $noarray[1] = 1;
}
```